# How to loop multiple elements within XML using Xquery

Tags: xquery

I have the following XML

```
<Item>
  <line>1</line>
  <itemno>ABC</itemno>
  <qty>3</qty>
  <serialnos>
    <serial>ABC1</serial>
    <serial>ABC2</serial>
    <serial>ABC3</serial>
  </serialnos>
  <Trackingnos>
    <trno>ABCT1</trno>
    <trno>ABCT2</trno>
    <trno>ABCT3</trno>
  </Trackingnos>
</Item>
```

Now the problem is I have convert them to the following format

```
<Line>
<opn>ABC</opn>
<qty>3</qty>
<serialCollection>
 <serials>
   <lineno>1</lineno>
   <serial>ABC1</serial>
   <trk>ABCT1</trk>
 </serials>
<serials>
   <lineno>1</lineno>
   <serial>ABC2</serial>
   <trk>ABCT2</trk>
 </serials>
<serials>
   <lineno>1</lineno>
   <serial>ABC3</serial>
   <trk>ABCT3</trk>
 </serials>
</serialCollection>
</Line>
```

The problem I have is the combination of serials and tracking number in the source xml can vary. 
For ex: 
there can be 3 serials and the tracking number can only be 1
or
there can be 3 serials and the tracking number can be 3
or 
there can be no serials and the tracking number can be 3
or 
there can be no serials and the tracking number can be 2

If the tracking number and serials are equal then i can assign one to one.
If the tracking numbers are less than serials then I have to randomly pick the last tracking number and assign it to the remaining serials.

If there are no serials, below would be the output

```
 <Line>
    <opn>ABC</opn>
    <qty>3</qty>
    <serialCollection>
     <serials>
       <lineno>1</lineno>
       </serial>
       <trk>ABCT1</trk>
     </serials>
    <serials>
       <lineno>1</lineno>
       </serial>
       <trk>ABCT2</trk>
     </serials>
    <serials>
       <lineno>1</lineno>
       </serial>
       <trk>ABCT3</trk>
     </serials>
    </serialCollection>
    </Line>
```

Similarly if the tracking numbers are not there they would be empty.

I have to do this transformation in Xquery but I am unable to do this. Can someone please help?

Comment: It's unclear what the output should be when there are no serials, but there are tracking numbers.

Comment: Updated the post as to how the result should look when they are not there

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, the `serialCollection` will always contain `serial` elements equal to either the number of tracking numbers or to the number of serial numbers, whichever is greater. You can calculate that using `fn:max`, and iterate over a generated sequence of numbers to create the correct number of elements.

Next, you want to select the tracking number and serial number corresponding to the position in the sequence, unless the tracking number at that position is empty, in which case you want to select the last tracking number. Generate a sequence containing both elements and select the first item of the sequence. If the first one is empty, the second one will be selected.

```
declare function local:transform(
  $item as element(Item)
) as element(Line)
{
  element Line {
    $item/itemno/element opn { string() },
    $item/qty
    ,
    let $tracking-numbers := $item/Trackingnos/trno
    let $serial-numbers := $item/serialnos/serial
    let $len := max((count($tracking-numbers), count($serial-numbers)))
    where ($len gt 0)
    return element serialCollection {
      for $i in (1 to $len)
      return element serials {
        $item/line/element lineno { string() },
        element serial { $serial-numbers[$i]/string() },
        element trk { ($tracking-numbers[$i], $tracking-numbers[last()])[1]/string() }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Wst, I am trying to do this

Comment: @ChandraShekarBairi Are you having a problem using this function?